# Kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of all real $2 \times 3$ matrices, and let $W$ be a vector space of all $4 \times 1$ column vectors. Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $V$ onto $W$. Then, what is the dimension of $\{ v \in V \mid T(v) = 0 \}$?

I do not understand the meaning of vector space of "matrices", and linear transformation "onto".

Comment: $n\times p$ matrices have a  vector space structure since you ccan add them and multiply them by a real  number, and these operations have all the  properties required for a vector space. `Onto` means the linear transformation $T$  is surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{dim}(V)=2\times 3=6$ and $\operatorname{dim}(w)=4\times 1=4$

$\operatorname{rk}(T) + \operatorname{nul}(T) = \operatorname{dim}(V)$ since $T$ is onto $\operatorname{rk}(T)=\operatorname{dim}(w)=4$ thus $\operatorname{nul}(T)=2$.

$\ker T=\{ v \in V \mid T(v) = 0 \}$ and its dimension is $\operatorname{nul}(T)$.

For more information see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: So, I don't really need to bother myself imagining what the vector spaces are, but just using rank-nullity theorem was enough. Thank you, pretty much helpful.

Comment: welcome dear :)